# Use view inside fragment on creation

Tags: android, fragment

I have a listview inside a fragment. I am trying to populate the listview once it has been inflated and referenced.

My first attempt was to reference the listview in the `onCreate` method of the fragment, but it had not been inflated yet by the `onCreateView` method, and so no reference could be made, and the list was remaining null.

I then tried to reference the list in the `onCreateView` method as some people suggested. However this seems to be called *after* the `onCreate` method. Therefore I can't do any initialization in the `onCreate` method, and the `onCreateView` seems to be a bad place to put my initialization code (such as setting the list adapter). What is the correct way to inflate and reference the listview inside the fragment, then immediately begin using the listview in code?

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    List<Item> itemList;
    ListAdapter adapter;        
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {        
            itemList = getItemList();
            context = getCtxt();   

        adapter = new ListAdapter(itemList, context);
        if (list != null && adapter != null)
            list.setAdapter(adapter); // never reached, as list is always null here
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fragment only contains a ListView you should extend ListFragment and populate it in onActivityCreated().

Comment: The `onActivityCreated()` method worked perfectly, thanks. I didn't think it would work inside a normal `Fragment` - but it did! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you have misunderstood the [**lifecycle of Fragment**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). 
I suggest you to have a look at the documentation.

Be aware that your onCreate is called before than onCreateView

**Don't retain the Context reference** because the fragment can be detached and the Context is not always valid.

Try something like this.

public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

```
ListView list;
List<Item> itemList;
ListAdapter adapter;        
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);      
     itemList = getItemList();
     adapter = new ListAdapter(itemList, getActivity());
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}